# sum up the score of two quiz and show it to the menu

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So guys I have two quiz and when the user do both of them i want to show into the menu the sum of user's score.Here is the part of my code that has relation with my question:

**Quiz 1:**

```
Intent intentt=new Intent(multiplechoicek1.this,menuaskisewn1.class);
intentt.putExtra("scoree",mscore);
startActivity(intentt);
```

**Quiz 2:**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(diagwnismakefalaio1.this,menuaskisewn1.class);
intent.putExtra("score",mScore);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Menu**

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
int score=intent.getIntExtra("score",0);
Intent intentt=getIntent();
int scoree=intentt.getIntExtra("scoree",0);
int athroisma=score+scoree;
currentscore.setText("To σκορ σου είναι: "+ athroisma +"/24");
```

When i test the app it shows only the sum of correct answers of 1 quiz..i suppose that this is because when it calls the oncreate method when one quiz is over the intent from the second quiz gets the default value...so it nevers sums up the correct answers of both quiz.(I didnt use sharedpreferences cause i dont want to store data after the app is closed).Any ideas? Thank you and sorry for bad English :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are starting "menuaskisewn1" activity from "multiplechoicek1" and "diagwnismakefalaio1" with "startActivity" method, it will create new activity of "menuaskisewn1" and then "menuaskisewn1" will get only extras from that intent which was called last time. so you have only one intent extra instead of both at a time.

Also you don't want to save data in shared preference.

In this case you can create a class which extends "Application" class and then take two static variable within it. In this way you can access those variable in every activity and also you can sum up those two variables in which ever activity you want. By using this way, you don't have to pass those in intent extras.

Make sure your manifest file will use that application class.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how and when you execute the code for opening the `menuaskisewn1` activity, but it seems that you are opening it twice, why? 
Then when `menuaskisewn1` is opened, it seems like you want to get 2 different intents with:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
```

but what you are doing is getting the same intent twice and this is the intent that started the activity, because **an activity is started by 1 Intent only**. 
So this intent contains either the extra with key `"score"` and this is saved in `score` or the extra with key `"scoree"` and this is saved in `scoree` but **not both**. 
So one of the variables `score` or `scoree` is `0` and when you add them the result is the same as one of the variables.
What you can do is start only once the activity and put 2 extra values:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(multiplechoicek1.this,menuaskisewn1.class);
intent.putExtra("score1", mscore1);
intent.putExtra("score2", mscore2);
startActivity(intent);
```

and get the values when the activity opens:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
int score1=intent.getIntExtra("score1",0);
int score2=intent.getIntExtra("score2",0);
int athroisma=score1+score2;
currentscore.setText("To σκορ σου είναι: "+ athroisma +"/24");
```